# Can't setCellValueFactory in a TableView for an array of floats

Tags: javafx

I'm trying to set the CellValueFactory for an array I have and this doesn't work. The variable I want in it is the Vaca.ordenha[].

```
TableColumn<Vaca, String>[] colunasOrdenhas = new TableColumn[concurso.getQtdOrdenhas()];
for (int i = 0; i < concurso.getQtdOrdenhas(); i++) {
    colunasOrdenhas[i]  = new TableColumn<>((i+1) + "ª ordenha");
    colunasOrdenhas[i].setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("ordenha[" + Integer.toString(i) + "]"));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access anything but the return value of a getter/the value wrapped in the property returned by the property getter by using `PropertyValueFactory`. You need to write your own `cellValueFactory` implementation.

Assuming there is a `getOrdenha()` method in `Vaca` returning `float[]` arrays of a length of at least `concurso.getQtdOrdenhas()`:

```
TableColumn<Vaca, Number>[] colunasOrdenhas = new TableColumn[concurso.getQtdOrdenhas()];
for (int i = 0; i < concurso.getQtdOrdenhas(); i++) {
    colunasOrdenhas[i]  = new TableColumn<>((i+1) + "ª ordenha");
    final int index = i;
    colunasOrdenhas[i].setCellValueFactory(cd -> new SimpleFloatProperty(cd.getValue().getOrdenha()[index]));
}
```

`cd.getValue()` returns the row item so you could use any other way of retrieving the value to display, if the above assumptions are incorrect. If the type of the column is different, you could use different `ObservableValue` implementation to wrap the value.